# Technology advice for mobile application

Tags: node.js, performance, react-native, mobile-application

I would like to develop a mobile game, kind of like an interactive ARG.
The players would see POI-s on a map, and they can interact with them in various ways. Some interactions on a POI should be visible to other players real time, and players should receive push notifications when a new POI appears in their area.

Up until now, I mostly worked with web technologies, so I figured a Node.js for backend, and a React Native for the application would be nice choices and I could learn both along the way. Since I have little experience with both, and don't really know about their capabilities performance-wise.
Are these technologies a good choice for an application like this? Is there a reason to go full native iOS/Android instead of React Native?
Could Node.js and React Native handle like 1-200k players daily? (It will probably never get there, lol)
I know it's just a pet project, but I'm interested in what would be the "industry standard" stack for something like this?

Comment: even if you go Native IOS/Android, you still need Node.js or some backend programming so you offload heavy processing there instead of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would think using React native should be fine for this genre of game for your frontend/client.  Where it seem to involves a lot of point click, drag and drop, present player with information.  If more real time rendering and interactivity then you may need to use a library/framework that are suitable for more real time rendering and interactivity.

As for the backend using Node.js is fine for handling your data requests.  For scaling to support lots of user, then that's quite a big topic that you'll need to work out.  You'll typically have to look at how complex your data/requests are and so how much your server can handle the load.  From there you will need to load balance on multiple servers.

For game or any type of application, where you need a backend it's very similar in needs.  You'll use a language that's best for backend development and performance.  From there you have to serve it and scale accordingly base on your loads.  You can leverage AWS or other cloud providers to do a lot of these.

Hopefully this answer some of the things you're asking for.